# XtraSchedule to display custom appointment caption

Tags: c#, devexpress, schedule

I want to change the **caption** of every **appointment** i have instead of displaying the **time** of the app
I tried `InitAppointmentDisplayText` event but it only changes the toolTip of the app

```
private void schedulerControl1_InitAppointmentDisplayText(object sender, AppointmentDisplayTextEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Text = string.Format("Schedule: {0}, Time: {1}", e.Appointment.Description, e.Appointment.Start.ToShortTimeString());
            e.Description = string.Format("Schedule: {0}, Time: {1}", e.Appointment.Description, e.Appointment.Start.ToShortTimeString());
        }
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should handle the InitAppointmentDisplayText event and also set the Scheduler.Views.MonthView properties as shown below:

```
schedulerControl1.Views.MonthView.AppointmentDisplayOptions.EndTimeVisibility = DevExpress.XtraScheduler.AppointmentTimeVisibility.Never;

schedulerControl1.Views.MonthView.AppointmentDisplayOptions.StartTimeVisibility = DevExpress.XtraScheduler.AppointmentTimeVisibility.Never;

schedulerControl1.Views.MonthView.AppointmentDisplayOptions.TimeDisplayType = DevExpress.XtraScheduler.AppointmentTimeDisplayType.Text;

        private void schedulerControl1_InitAppointmentDisplayText(object sender, DevExpress.XtraScheduler.AppointmentDisplayTextEventArgs e) {
            e.Text = "test";
        }
```

**UPDATE**

Please refer to the following topics in our documentation to learn how to implement custom edit forms:

[How to: Create a Custom EditAppointment Form with Custom Fields](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument2288)

[How to: Create a Custom Appointment Recurrence Form](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument2880)

Comment: Thanks it works, I'm wondering what is the event that I must handle in order to capture the appointment **double click** in order to edit it with custom interface, I tried `EditAppointmentFormShowing` & `EditRecurrentAppointmentFormShowing` but nothing helped, I used `EditAppointmentFormShowing` to create **new appointment** with custom interface but the event did not trigger for editing!

Comment: is there any property i must set or change before in order to trigger the `ditRecurrentAppointmentFormShowing` when double clicking the app?

Comment: The event should be triggered when an appointment is double clicked.  Please set the breakpoint there and check if this event is triggered.  If not, I recommend that you create a new ticket in the Support center (http://www.devexpress.com/support/center) and post your code there.  We will take a look at it and let you know the cause of the problem.  Finally, please make certain that the SchedulerControl.OptionsCustomization.AllowAppointmentEdit is set to All